# How to sum first Column on netstat result

Tags: networking, freebsd, netstat, server-administration

I want to count the packets of an interface like ix1 . The result of netstat -I ix1 -w1 is something like this .

```
  input          (ix1)           output
```

packets  errs idrops      bytes    packets  errs      bytes colls

```
     0     0     0          0          0     0          0     0
```

1042563     0     0  794182232          0     0          0     0

1537437     0     0 1177837768          0     0          0     0

```
     0     0     0          0          0     0          0     0
```

who can I get sum of the fist column ? I tried with grep but it is not handy would you please help how to do it ? with grep or cut or ....?

Comment: I m not familiar with awk :(

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer with awk . this is the answer . $1 is the column you want

```
netstat -I ix1 -w1 | awk ' { print s } { s += $1}'
```

and with this  command you can have more than 1 Column

```
netstat -I ix1 -w1 | awk ' { print "input: "s"    output: "ss } { s += $1}  { ss += $5}'
```